# Track other app from my app - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any provision to track(usage time) of any app from another app in iOS?
For example:- I have developed an app named "**A**" and I want to track usage time of another app installed in my device(iPhone or Android) named "**B**". By usage time, I mean how much time a user had used the app. Would it be possible?

Another scenario:- Is it possible to track usage time of native app(like mail, camera, message,etc) from our app?
I think this is not possible in iOS, but not sure about it.
 Does anyone have any idea of this?
**Note:-** I don't want to track my app usage using Google analytics.

Comment: Downvote with a reason or comment would be appreciated.

Comment: I can see Apple wouldn't allow tracking of native apps (mail, camera etc) do to this being a huge security issue. tracking your own apps would require you to write your own tracking software (obviously it would have to connect to some server to submit the data) or use google analytics (Which you have said you don't want to use) or something simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't!

All the application in iOS runs in sandbox mode.

If you want to track your application usage you have to connect it to the server with (ex) REST interface.

**EDIT:**
Just bump on the idea...
If you writing for iOS7 you can use `Shared Keychain` feature. You can send there all usage statistics and receiving it by other app. Should work!

Check this out: http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/

Comment: Can you please share any link in support of this?

Comment: I checked the link, but that is for the case if we have developed both the apps.

Comment: Daa. of course, otherwise is in sandbox mode and you absolutely can't get access to it! This is what i post in the beginning. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html

Answer (score 1):

If both apps are signed by the same App Store Developer account, then they can both share an iCloud data store. Just store the usage time in iCloud and it'll work perfectly.

You cannot track any app by any other developer, the security model does not allow it.

Comment: Can you please share any link in support of this?